# Removing old Entry Door dead bolt lock

Tags: lock

Attached is the picture of circa 1987 dead bolt lock from the back after removing the back plate. Could not find manufacturer name but seems like Kwikset based on key types. The front of the lock would not come out even with pry bar. How to remove the lock for re-keying?c

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use a flat head screwdriver to unscrew the hollow bolts to the left and right of the center shaft.  It's a little strange if you've never seen it before, but those are actually barrel screws with internal and external  threads.

Comment: New to me, though I think I'd have noticed the screwdriver slots and tried 'em

Comment: The strange part is that the screws that hold on the thumb latch side screw into those bolts so your mind doesn't really register that those _also_ unscrew.  It's a cool screw inside of a screw arrangement.