# How can I remove this Kwikset entry door dead bolt lock?

Tags: lock, removal, deadbolt

This is a picture of the Kwikset dead bolt from interior. I removed the outer layer. However, I'm having trouble removing the bottom plate.

This looks very similar to this question: [Removing old Entry Door dead bolt lock](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78602/removing-old-entry-door-dead-bolt-lock). However, mine doesn't have the inner screwdriver slot. There is nothing for screwdriver to sit and rotate as can be seen from the picture below:

[image: Deadbolt image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two small indentations in the screwheads that a large screwdriver will fit into for screw removal.

Comment: @bugrizm the benefit of taking a picture and zooming in- you can see those things normally hidden in the dark!

Comment: Roughly translated: USE A BIGGER SCREWDRIVER!!! :-)

Comment: its amazing what one can see in a photo that is not seen when using one's eyeball. i often snap a photo on my phone to then look at it in detail ...